# XSLT: insert elements if they are not present

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to update lots of xml files with simple configuration. The problem which I have - the `config` element is optional in my xml files and they can already have some configuration.

So what I want to do:

1. Insert `<config/>` with all predefined `element`'s if it's missing
2. Insert missing `element` into `config` tag. If they were there already - leave as it was.

**before**:

```
<root>
  <config> <!-- this is optional. can be not defined at all -->
    <element2 attr="c"/>
  </config>
</root>
```

**What I want to get**:

```
<root>
  <config> 
    <element1 attr="a"/>
    <element2 attr="b"/> <!-- not override this one, but insert if missing -->
    <element3 attr="c"/>
  </config>
</root>
```

So my thoughts were to have several templates and apply 1st step if it's not there, and do second step within separate `mode`. But it didn't worked out.

UPD.
I'm using xslt 1.0, but I'm guessing switching to 2.0 will be not a problem.

Predefined elements are:

```
<element1 attr="a"/>
<element2 attr="b"/>
<element3 attr="c"/>
```

Comment: Which version of XSLT do you use? Which exactly are the predefined elements you need to add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, you should look at this from the opposite end; that is suppress any existing `config` and install your own, using either existing values from the original `config` or - if none are found - your default values.

Here's an **XSLT 1.0** implementation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="cfg" match="config/*" use="local-name()" />

<xsl:variable name="default-cfg">
    <element1 attr="a"/>
    <element2 attr="b"/>
    <element3 attr="c"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="root" select="/"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <config> 
            <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($default-cfg)/*">
                <xsl:call-template name="cfg-element"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </config>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="config"/>

<xsl:template name="cfg-element">
    <xsl:variable name="name" select="name()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="default-value" select="@attr"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$root">
        <xsl:variable name="existing-element" select="key('cfg', $name)"/>
        <xsl:element name="{$name}">
            <xsl:attribute name="attr">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$existing-element">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$existing-element/@attr"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$default-value"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: picked your as an answer because it's xslt 1.0 and flexible one :)

Answer (score 4):

You want a near-identity transform with a couple of modifications.

First in English-like pseudo-code:

- in the template for `root`, handle the two cases separately:  if you have a `config` element, process it; otherwise, supply one.
- in the template for 'config', for each potential child element, handle the two cases separately:  if you have such an element, process it, otherwise supply such an element.

Now, in XSLT-like pseudo-code:

In the template for `root`, handle the two cases separately:

```
<xsl:template match='root'>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="config">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <config>
          <element1 attr="a"/>
          <element2 attr="b"/> 
          <element3 attr="c"/>
        </config>
      </
    </
  </
</
```

In your template for `config`, supply missing elements as needed.  If you have a fixed order, the code can just walk through them in order:

```
<xsl:template match='config'>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="element1">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="element1"/>
      </
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <element1 attr="a"/>
      </
    </
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="element2">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="element2"/>
      </
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <elementb attr="b"/>
      </
    </
    <!--* more chooses, as needed ... *-->
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="elementN">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="elementN"/>
      </
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <elementN attr="N"/>
      </
    </
  </
</
```

If the order is unconstrained, this can be a little simpler:

```
<xsl:template match="config">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:if test="not(element1)">
      <element1 attr="a"/>
    </
    <xsl:if test="not(element2)">
      <element2 attr="b"/>
    </
    <!--* etc ... *-->
  </
</
```

Unless you're doing something more complicated than you show, I don't see a need for an additional mode here.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="cfg-els-by-name" match="config/*" use="node-name(.)"/>

<xsl:param name="default">
  <config>
    <element1 attr="a"/>
    <element2 attr="b"/>
    <element3 attr="c"/>
  </config>
</xsl:param>

<xsl:variable name="main-doc" select="/"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root[not(config)]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$default/config"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root/config">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="* , $default/config/*[not(key('cfg-els-by-name', node-name(.), $main-doc))]">
      <xsl:sort select="local-name(.)"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am not sure whether the order of `config` child element is determined by sorting on `local-name()`.